# Function that returns keyboard input when it's get

Tags: javascript, canvas, input

I'm writing a game in JavaScript with HTML canvas. I have a need for a function that waits for user to give input from keyboard in specified range, and then returns to place where it was called.

I have event listeners for key release, which pass value to variable 'collectedInput' only when 'waitingForInput' is true. Sadly, this bunch of code doesn't work. It just doesn't return to calling place.

```js
var getInput = function (startingIndex, endingIndex){
    waitingForInput = true;
    startingIndex = startingIndex? startingIndex: 1;//default range
    endingIndex = endingIndex? endingIndex: 6;
    if (collectedInput==0&&waitingForInput){
        setTimeout(getInput(startingIndex, endingIndex), 1000);
    }
    else if (collectedInput<startingIndex||collectedInput>endingIndex){
        setTimeout(getInput(startingIndex, endingIndex), 1000);
    }
    else{
        waitingForInput = false;
        return collectedInput;
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```js
var getInput = function(){
    while (collectedInput==0){
        pause(10);
    }
    return;
}
function pause(numberMillis) { 
    var now = new Date(); 
    var exitTime = now.getTime() + numberMillis; 
    while (true) { 
        now = new Date(); 
        if (now.getTime() > exitTime) 
            return; 
    } 
}
```

but it only crashed browser.

Comment: How do you set collectedInput value ?

Comment: The value of `getInput` when it's called inside a `setTimeout` it's not stored anywhere. Plus, the first parameter of `setTimeout` must be a function. There you are executing the function so you are setting as a first paramater the returned value of `getInput`

Comment: @dilantha111 
```js
function numberGUI (key){
 if (waitingForInput){
  collectedInput = key;
  waitingForInput = false;
 }
}
```

Comment: @MaxiDiaz 'collectedInput' is a global variable and tbh i don't really need it returned, I'd rather like to make the execution jump back to another function, where it is called. `getInput` is rather operating on global variables than passing anything